# Getting InnerHits Result from SearchHits Class at Spring Data Elastic Search 4.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am currently doing migration from spring data elastic search 3.2.X to 4.0.0.

I had been relying on obtaining inner hits result through raw SearchResponse class by utilizing the now deprecated low level function **org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations.query(SearchQuery query, ResultsExtractor resultsExtractor);**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-3.2-4.0

Basically what I did was creating custom resultExtractor which will expose the low level SearchResponse so that I could then extract the inner hits result.

Now with version 4.0.0 that functionality is no longer there, Both ElasticSearchOperations and ElasticSearchRestTemplate utilize new result class called SearchHits which AFAIK does not store inner hits information.

The workaround I could think of besides using the restHighLevelClient directly (which of course is undesirable since I'd lose the object mapping and stuff) is to extend ElasticSearchRestTemplate and basically creating new implementation of **search(Query query, Class clazz, IndexCoordinates index)** which will return SearchHits and the raw search response (similar to what my custom ResultExtractor used to do).

Afterwards, since all api returning page instance has been deprecated, I would now have to rely on **SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(SearchHits searchHits, @Nullable Pageable pageable)** to get the usual paging functionalities.

I felt that this is not very straightforward and clean solution and certainly felt more like a workaround. Would there be any more straightforward way to obtain innerHitsResult and map result content to page at version 4.0.0?

Comment: I understand that is is fixed into spring data ES 4.1 according to the JIRA. As i am using spring boot 2.3.4, I don't know if I can benefit from that. My requirement is similar as I want to get the scripted fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-263) about inner_hits. Returning the *inner_hits* should be done in the `SearchHit<T>` class and not by exposing internal Elasticsearch data.

As for the paging: When you have a `SearchHits<T>` object as the result of a query that use a `Pageable`, you can call

```
SearchHits<Entity> searchHits = operations.search(query, Entity.class);
SearchPage<Entity> page = SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, query.getPageable)
```

`SearchPage` implements the `Page` interface.

**Edit:**

The issue is fixed, inner hits are returned from the next version (4.1) on.

Comment: Hi @P.J.Meisch thanks for your answer and for pointing out the Jira ticket. It seems that the ticket has been left unresolved since 2016 :(. I guess obtaining inner hits from search response is the only way to go for now...

Comment: I mean I would prefer to obtain inner hits result from search hit too if its possible since it will also simplify my code. However, as has been pointed out that searchHit class simply doesnt store any inner hit info

Comment: currently it doesn't, we have to add it. We want to have solutions for problems like this for every user, if we were to expose the raw Elasticsearch data, everyone would have to write it's own parsing code. As for the ticket being open for so long: yes, we have these. I took over maintenance of this project in april 2019. This is a community driven project, and there is not really much contribution. Many of these old tickets don't fit the code or the internal structure anymore, so they will have to be discussed until they can be implemented

Comment: @P.K.Meisch I understand your position and absolutely agree that in the future, a robust solution is neccessary (perhaps the inner hits annotation way mentioned at Jira ticket). Having said that,  I just kinda think that at the moment removing the old low level org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations.query(SearchQuery query, ResultsExtractor resultsExtractor); is kinda premature considering that SearchHit class does not encapsulate all data from SearchResponse yet.

Comment: "The method org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations.query(SearchQuery query, ResultsExtractor<T> resultsExtractor); and the org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ResultsExtractor interface have been removed. These could be used to parse the result from Elasticsearch for cases in which the response mapping done with the Jackson based mapper was not enough. Since version 4.0, there are the new Search Result Types to return the information from an Elasticsearch response, so there is no need to expose this low level functionality."

Comment: Perhaps above section at the documentation can be made clearer with Inner Hits (or any other unmapped section at SearchResponse) notes. Because If I am totally new with Elastic Search, after reading the above, I would assume that whatever data ES return to me would also be available in SearchHit class, Cheers

Comment: I am just evaluating how to return this; I have set up an index with cities containing house containing inhabitants and will see how to get this into a SearchHit (embedded List of SearchHit objects, I have to find the best type for these inner ones).

Comment: In my opinion, it would be best if we are able to get the inner hit result at the declared java bean itself, for example inhabitants inner hits should automatically populate city.inhabitants if user desire, the settings being determined by annotation perhaps. If the inner hits result appear in individual SearchHit with Object or Generic type user would still have to "combine" them to the bean.

Comment: Its not as simple as just replacing one property in the returned entity. Inner hits can be nested across several entities. In the `InnerHitsTest` class I use a `City`, containing a `House` list which in turn contains an `Inhabitant` list. I then search for `City` objects with inner hits for `Inhabitants`. Elasticsearch returns all complete serach hits in addition to the inner hits...

Comment: So to set the result to only contain the returned inner hits `Inhabitant` objects we would need to first clear the inhabitant's list of every house, and then evaluate the nested metadata offset values to put the inner hits inhabitants into their respective houses again and in a final step remove all houses that have no inhabitants. This then invalidates all the nested metadata offsets as now the offsets for the houses are wrong.
If this is the desired behaviour, it should be done in the application code, but not in the library.

Comment: I have seen your commit for inner hits, it loooks good, Thank you. for the above problem, I was thinking that for city-inhabitant case, if we intend to merge the inner hits result to java bean, we could perhaps "move" the inner hits level from inhabitants to the second most outer level (house in this case), so that instead of returning inhabitants, the inner hits would return house and can be easily joined to city. But then again, maybe this behavior is a bit too much for library

Comment: Elasticsearch does not return the _houses_. It returns the top level hits and the inner hits. And even though the most cases probably will not have structures nested deeper than one level, it still is possible. Imagine my example with the top level not being cities but countries and have a nested search for inhabitants. We can't decide what would be the best level to put the inner hits to.

Comment: In my case i am looking to get scripted fields results with 4.0.0. It seems I have no way to do this anymore.  (without the Custom ResultsExtractor)

Comment: @christophespielmann scripted fields are a different story. Have you looked at `@ScriptedField`?