# How to increase response size in elasticsearch with spring-data using @Query annotation?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, java-8, spring-data

Currently the below query is only returning 10 search hits. I want to increase it to 100. How to do it??

````
    @Query("{\"match\": {\"metaData.transcript1\": {\"query\": \"?0\",\"fuzziness\": \"AUTO\",\"prefix_length\": \"0\",\"max_expansions\": \"100\",\"boost\": \"1.0\"}}}")
    @Highlight(fields = {@HighlightField(name = "metaData.transcript1")}, parameters = @HighlightParameters(
            preTags = "<em>",
            postTags = "</em>",
            fragmentSize = 50
            numberOfFragments = 3
        ))
    List<SearchHit<Audio>> findByKeyword(String query);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Page

```
  @Query("{\"match\": {\"metaData.transcript1\": {\"query\": \"?0\",\"fuzziness\": \"AUTO\",\"prefix_length\": \"0\",\"max_expansions\": \"100\",\"boost\": \"1.0\"}}}")
    @Highlight(fields = {@HighlightField(name = "metaData.transcript1")}, parameters = @HighlightParameters(
            preTags = "<em>",
            postTags = "</em>",
            fragmentSize = 50
            numberOfFragments = 3
        ))
    Page<SearchHit<Audio>> findByKeyword(String query,Pageable pageable);
```

and use like it

```
Page<SearchHit<Audio>> audios = repository.findAll("query_string",PageRequest.of(0, 100));
```

Comment: SearchHit doesn't work with Page...

Got this Exception: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.NoSuchIndexException: Index [SearchHit] not found.; nested exception is [SearchHit] ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=index_not_found_exception, reason=no such index [SearchHit]]]

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115096/getting-innerhits-result-from-searchhits-class-at-spring-data-elastic-search-4-0